# Environment variable in app.json in Heroku not working

Tags: heroku

I have an app.json that looks like this (roughly):

```
{
  "addons": [
    "heroku-postgresql"
  ],
  "env": {
    "RAILS_MASTER_KEY": {
      "description": "Key to decrypt Rails credentials.",
      "require": true,
      "generator": "secret"
    },
    "SAFE_EMAIL_DEST": {
      "description": "Where to send emails when in safe mode.",
      "required": false
    }
  },
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "scripts": {
        "test": "bundle exec rake spec"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "env": {
        "SAFE_EMAIL_DEST": "staging@example.com"
      }
    },
    "production": {
    }
  }
}
```

but when I run the app, I get the error: `RuntimeError (SAFE_EMAIL_DEST needs to be defined)` meaning, that environment variable is not defined.

What am I missing? Why isn't it being defined? Is "staging" the correct environment name for an app in the staging state in a Heroku pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

For `environments` key in app.json, only 2 are understood by the platform:

- `test`: applied to continuous integration environments created by Heroku CI.
- `review`: applied to Review Apps environments created by Heroku Review Apps.

so basically you need to set up directly in the `env` key your `"SAFE_EMAIL_DEST"` variable :

```
{
  "addons": [
    "heroku-postgresql"
  ],
  "env": {
    "RAILS_MASTER_KEY": {
      "description": "Key to decrypt Rails credentials.",
      "require": true,
      "generator": "secret"
    },
    "SAFE_EMAIL_DEST": {
      "description": "Where to send emails when in safe mode.",
      "value": "staging@example.com"
    }
  },
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "scripts": {
        "test": "bundle exec rake spec"
      },
      "env": {
        "SAFE_EMAIL_DEST": "Your SAFE_EMAIL_DEST for continuous integration environments"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#environments)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean at the beginning. I have a pipeline with two apps, staging and production, and the tests. I'm not sure what you mean by `[your-project-name]-staging`.

Comment: The way you set up SAFE_EMAIL_DEST in that snippet looks like it would apply to all environments in the pipeline, not just staging.

Comment: Yep you can only set default values of env variables in app.json as it describe only one application in heroku, not entire pipeline. You need to manually update variables from heroku dashboard or with heroku-ci : `heroku config:set KEY=VALUE -a [app-name]` after creating pipeline.

Comment: I know how to set the environment variables from the command line or the we UI. What did you mean by the first paragraph on your answer, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: (Ok sry for my english) I imagine that you want to create "ready-to-deploy" application on heroku with one and only one app.json and maybe with the `pipeline:setup` command to create entire pipeline in the same time; If you do it that way, you can't set environment variable for each pipeline status (staging / prod).

Comment: It might make sense to explain how you're supposed to override settings for staging, given that you can't have a "staging" key, which is that the staging app is permanent, therefore you don't need an override. You just add the environment variable (or whatever other change) to staging once, and then you never have to do it again. (I think there's an automated way to setup apps but that's something that probably a much smaller subset of people do.)